# Simple Jsoup code for Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I recently started developing programs in Android, and have a small problem with this simple code. I am trying to parse the **title** of a website and stored in a string, but so far unsuccessful. Is it because I am not doing it in Async ? Or can it be a different issues all together?

[image: http://s9.postimg.org/ikycjit9b/android.png]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnSearch;
    private EditText editTextCarReg;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //-------------------------------------------------
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
        //------------------------------------------------
        editTextCarReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRegistration);
        editTextCarReg.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void example() throws IOException
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://http://9gag.com/").get();
        String title = doc.title();
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == btnSearch.getId())
        {
            try {
                example();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


}
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, i try both Maxim and user1920666, and they work. users1920666 way seams more 'hackish' but its also more simple. I think I will use it for now until I get more experience in the topic. Kudos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logs:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

Run `Jsoup logic` in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

(be sure that you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` as well)

You can write something like:

```
class JsoupTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected void doInBackground(String... url) {
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
       String title = doc.title();
       ...

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
        // here you can update your UI thread through Handler, for example
    }
}
```

And call, like:

```
new JsoupTask().execute(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

write this code before your request

```
if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
                ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
            }
```

Using asynctask is better practice.